# Mongo compound array Index not being used

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I have the following object structure in my database.

```
{
  "_id": 1234,
  "dateTime": ISODate("2015-09-28T02:15:00Z"),
  "tags":[{
     "_id": 5678,
     "name":{
       "short": "GOT",
       "long" : "Game of Thrones"
     }
   },{
     "_id": 9101,
     "name":{
       "short": "Dragons",
       "long" : "Huge Dragons"
     }
  }]
}
```

I am trying to query using:

> db.collection.find({
>       dateTime: { $gte: new Date(1443398000000), $lt: new Date(1443484740000) }, 
>       "tags._id": "d8408d19-48e4-36a0-aa23-55cd8c8415f6"}})

I created the index:

> { dateTime: 1, "tags._id": 1}

Yet when running the query with explain() it never uses this index.

I have tried flipping the index the other way round and re ordering my query but this did not help.

I have around 500,000 documents in my database.

Hopefully someone can help.

Comment: Can you include the output of `.explain(true)` for your query? Also, what specific version of MongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I just query like this

```
> db.comp.find({dateTime:{"$gte":new Date(12345),"$lte":new Date(999999999)},"ta
gs._id":5678}).explain()
```

and here is the output

```
{
        "queryPlanner" : {
                "plannerVersion" : 1,
                "namespace" : "test.comp",
                "indexFilterSet" : false,
                "parsedQuery" : {
                        "$and" : [
                                {
                                        "tags._id" : {
                                                "$eq" : 5678
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "dateTime" : {
                                                "$lte" : ISODate("1970-01-12T13:
46:39.999Z")
                                        }
                                },
                                {
                                        "dateTime" : {
                                                "$gte" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:
00:12.345Z")
                                        }
                                }
                        ]
                },
                "winningPlan" : {
                        "stage" : "KEEP_MUTATIONS",
                        "inputStage" : {
                                "stage" : "FETCH",
                                "filter" : {
                                        "dateTime" : {
                                                "$gte" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:
00:12.345Z")
                                        }
                                },
                                "inputStage" : {
                                        "stage" : "IXSCAN",
                                        "keyPattern" : {
                                                "dateTime" : 1,
                                                "tags._id" : 1
                                        },
                                        "indexName" : "dateTime_1_tags._id_1",
                                        "isMultiKey" : true,
                                        "direction" : "forward",
                                        "indexBounds" : {
                                                "dateTime" : [
                                                        "(true, new Date(9999999
99)]"
                                                ],
                                                "tags._id" : [
                                                        "[5678.0, 5678.0]"
                                                ]
                                        }
                                }
```

If you see `"indexName" : "dateTime_1_tags._id_1"` index been used.

Hope it will help

Comment: it doesn't select the right query for me, I get the single index bounds of dateTime. If I hint to use the correct index the performance is really bad, 70 seconds to return

Comment: I just fire the same query db.comp.find({dateTime:{"$gte":new Date(1443398000000),"$lt":new Date(1443484740000)},"tags._id":5678}).explain() which you mentioned in Question and getting the same result. Do you find any gap in this query ?

Comment: No your query looks fine, how big of a dataset are you running this against, try and create 500,000 docs with random timestamps in the dateTime field, I do also have a index on dateTime by itself, this is the one it selects

Comment: Are you using any kind of sorting ?